# Почему после первого нажатия кнопки, она больше не работает

Tags: javascript, html

```
<h1 id="lineCombo">Комбо тут</h1>
<script>
changeLineCombo.onclick = function () {
document.getElementById('lineCombo').style.marginLeft='-20px';
}
</script>
```

Надо сделать чтобы при повторном нажатии оно ещё раз делало '-20px'
Но после первого нажатия дальше не работает(

Comment: вы минусуете 20px один раз, как если бы это было = -20px, а не -= 20px

Answer (score 2):

```js
let init = -20;
document.getElementById('lineCombo').addEventListener('click',  function () {
  let left = document.getElementById('lineCombo');
  left.style.marginLeft = init + 'px';
  init += -20;
  console.log(left.style.marginLeft)
}
)
```

```html
<h1 id="lineCombo">Комбо тут</h1>
```